# Do I need to complete a Subject for it to be garbage collected?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I follow a cleanup pattern in my Angular components that looks like this:

```
class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private destroy$ = new Subject();

    ngOnInit() {
        service.someStream().takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(doSomething);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroy$.next(true);
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of automatically unsubscribing when the component is destroyed.

My question is: Does a reference to `destroy$` stick around indefinitely because I haven't called `this.destroy$.complete()`, or will it get GC'ed when the parent class is collected?

Comment: Even though you're not directly calling `complete()` on the Subject you complete the chain with the `takeUntil` operator which sends the `complete` signal and makes each operator to recursively unsubscribe. So it shouldn't matter whether the `complete` signal comes from the Subject or somewhere further down the chain.

Comment: @martin I think your answer is incorrect. For me takeUntil will complete the stream you apply the takeUntil on. Not the one used into the takeUntil. Take a look to the marble diagram : http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil Notice that when `z` is emitted, the final stream is closed but the stream containing `z` remains open. So Sean, yes you need to call the next and also the complete.

Comment: While I'm pretty sure that it will get GC'd when references to the parent class are removed. This pattern seems dubious to me, why are you not simply tracking the subscription and calling `unsubscribe` on it when you close down all your streams?

Comment: @paulpdaniels If you have multiple subscriptions you'd have to keep references to each of them and call unsubscribe on each in sequence. By using pattern above you can have a single subject that unsubscribes from them all at once. The result is less, and more readable, code.

Comment: @nej_simon, assuming that a component would call `ngOnInit` more than once, which itself sounds strange, this method is still more verbose than creating a new subscription and calling `Subscription#add` followed by `unsubscribe`, and it suffers a possible state inconsistency if the ordering  is incorrect and the `$destroy` call pre-empts the subscription.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Why would it need to call `ngOnInit` multiple times? In the above simplified code example, yes, but actual code may well be dealing with more subscriptions in `ngOnInit`. Explicitly creating a `Subscription` object is another way of doing something similar. I don't see how it's more verbose though nor why it would cause inconsistency. It's actually a pretty common way of doing it - see this post by Ben Lesh for ex. https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: @nej_simon The idea is that you only have to unsubscribe _once_ to tear down your pipelines, not that you never call unsubscribe. Note that even the article you linked builds up the subscriptions into a single pipeline which it then tears down in `unmount` with a single `unsubscribe` call. If you have multiple streams you can just compose them with `merge` and you still end up with a single `unsubscribe` to call at the "end of the world".

Comment: The OP is about garbage collecting the `subject`, why are the comments discussing how to garbage collect `subscriptions` ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you look at the source for [`Subject.complete`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.0/src/Subject.ts#L82-L94), you'll find the answer:

```
complete() {
  if (this.closed) {
    throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
  }
  this.isStopped = true;
  const { observers } = this;
  const len = observers.length;
  const copy = observers.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    copy[i].complete();
  }
  this.observers.length = 0;
}
```

Calling `complete` notifies any observers and then clears the array of observers. Unless you have an observer/subscriber that has a reference to the `Subject`, there is nothing in the `complete` implementation that would affect whether or not the `Subject` could be garbage collected.

RxJS pushes notifications to subscribers. Subscribers don't hold references to the observables; it's the other way around. So, unless you've explicitly created a subscriber that holds a reference to the `Subject` - via a closure or some other mechanism - there's no need to call `complete` for garbage-collection purposes.

Comment: Hey @cartant, thank you for your answer. Just so I'm clear, does having my `Subject` in a `takeUntil` count as an observer/subscriber having a reference to it? I assume no, because that subject is unsubscribed from once it emits, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: The use in `takeUntil` is fine, as the subject's reference to the observer will be removed via the `takeUntil`-initiated unsubscription. It's possible that the observer's reference would prevent the subject from being collected - depending upon what's referencing the observer - but that's a separate issue and is not related to whether or not `complete` is called on the subject.

Comment: @cartant, then this is a precaution, not a necessity [take-until-destroy.ts#L26](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy/blob/master/src/take-until-destroy.ts#L26), right? *I was just researching the same thing as OP, so please don't consider this as annoyance.*

Comment: So, basically calling subject.complete() clears the list of observers / subscriptions maintained inside the subject, it does not garbage collect the subject itself ?

Comment: "Subscribers don't hold references to the observables" - yes they do, through the Subscription object returned by any call to subscribe on the observable. These objects can prevent a Subject from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

The original post actually poses two questions:

- one in the title "Do I need to complete a Subject for it to be garbage collected?"

The answer to that question is "Yes, sometimes". So normally you should do a complete unless you know for sure it is not necessary. That is because any call to subscribe will return a Subscription object which does refer back to the observable. See, for example, https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs-primer#subscription.

(The statement in the answer [If you look at the source ... you'll find the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294453/929968): "Subscribers don't hold references to the observables..." is misleading. Maybe the subscriber itself does not hold a reference to the Observable - but the returned Subscription object does.)

This reference can stop the Subject being garbage collected - unless complete is called to remove the subscription, or it is  removed in some other way. Which leads to the second question in the post...

- the question implicit in the example: "Do I need to call complete on the subject in this example?".

In this particular example it is not necessary to call complete because the subscription to the subject, "destroy$", will have been created - and removed - by the takeUntil call. So if the OP wants to know whether a call to complete is needed in that particular example, the answer is no.